# removeClass from the parent dropdown when values change

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I got this script to work that is, to add class to the parent dropdown: `others`. However, on subsequent change of value in the dropdown, the class `activated` doesn't work anymore

**[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/25cy1rp0/)**

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div id="term" class="btn-group btn-group-toggle d-flex" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-primary w-100 active">
                <input type="radio" name="options" value="5" id="option1" autocomplete="off"> 5
              </label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary w-100">
                <input type="radio" name="options" value="10" id="option2" autocomplete="off"> 10
              </label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary w-100">
                <input type="radio" name="options" value="15" id="option3" autocomplete="off"> 15
              </label>
        <div class="btn-group btn-dropdown w-100">
          <label class="btn btn-primary w-100 dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          <input type="radio" class="" name="options" id="option4" autocomplete="off"> <span class="selection">Other</span> <span class="caret"></span>
                </label>
          <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
            <label class="btn btn-primary w-100">
                    <input type="radio" name="options" value="20" id="option3" autocomplete="off"> 20
                  </label>
            <label class="btn btn-primary w-100">
                    <input type="radio" name="options" value="25" id="option3" autocomplete="off"> 25
                  </label>
            <label class="btn btn-primary w-100">
                    <input type="radio" name="options" value="30" id="option3" autocomplete="off"> 30
                  </label>
            <label class="btn btn-primary w-100">
                    <input type="radio" name="options" value="35" id="option3" autocomplete="off"> 35
                  </label>
            <label class="btn btn-primary w-100">
                    <input type="radio" name="options" value="40" id="option3" autocomplete="off"> 40
                  </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(".dropdown-menu label").click(function(){
  var selText = $(this).text();
  $(this).parents('.btn-group').find('.selection').html(selText+' <span class="caret"></span>');
  $(this).parents('.btn-group').find('.dropdown-toggle').addClass('activated');
  $(this).parents('.btn-group').find('label').click(function(){
        $(this).parents('.btn-group').find('.dropdown-toggle').removeClass('activated');
        });
});
```

Look at the demo and try changing the value in the dropdown. The `activated` class gets added the first time in the parent but as you keep changing the values, it doesn't work anymore. How do I go about fixing this?

Comment: I can't figure out what you actually are tring to do, "one of the values from the dropdown is added and then changed", in the fiddle on Chrome, the dropdown 'active' does indeed get removed after a clicking on any of the items.

Comment: Edited the question again to make it simpler to understand. Updated the code and the link too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't add a click event handler inside another one:

```
$(this).parents('.btn-group').find('label').click(function(){
```

In this way you create as many click handlers as many times you click on first element.

Another issue is in this line:

```
$(".dropdown-menu label").click(function(){
```

Change that line to:

```
$('#term label').on('click', function(e) {
```

Now you can listen for every label and so you can do what necessary:

```
$('#term label').on('click', function(e) {
    if ($(this).closest('.btn-group').is('.btn-dropdown')) {
        var selText = $(this).text();
        var x = $(this).closest('.btn-group').find('.selection').html(selText + ' <span class="caret"></span>');
        $(this).closest('.btn-group').find('.dropdown-toggle').addClass('activated');
    } else {
        $(this).closest('.btn-group').find('.dropdown-toggle').removeClass('activated');
    }
});
```

```js
$('#term label').on('click', function(e) {
    if ($(this).closest('.btn-group').is('.btn-dropdown')) {
        var selText = $(this).text();
        var x = $(this).closest('.btn-group').find('.selection').html(selText + ' <span class="caret"></span>');
        $(this).closest('.btn-group').find('.dropdown-toggle').addClass('activated');
    } else {
        $(this).closest('.btn-group').find('.dropdown-toggle').removeClass('activated');
    }
});
```

```css
.btn-group .dropdown-menu.show {
    border: 2px solid blue;
    padding: 0;
}

.btn-group .dropdown-menu .btn {
    margin: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    border: 0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
}

.btn-group .dropdown-menu .btn input {
    position: absolute;
    clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.btn.btn-primary.w-100.dropdown-toggle.activated {
    background-color: #0f3b83;
    border: solid 2px #0f3b83;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div id="term" class="btn-group btn-group-toggle d-flex" data-toggle="buttons">
                <label class="btn btn-primary w-100 active">
                    <input type="radio" name="options" value="5" id="option1" autocomplete="off"> 5
                </label>
                <label class="btn btn-primary w-100">
                    <input type="radio" name="options" value="10" id="option2" autocomplete="off"> 10
                </label>
                <label class="btn btn-primary w-100">
                    <input type="radio" name="options" value="15" id="option3" autocomplete="off"> 15
                </label>

                <div class="btn-group btn-dropdown w-100">
                    <label class="btn btn-primary w-100 dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
                           aria-expanded="false">
                        <input type="radio" class="" name="options" id="option4" autocomplete="off"> <span
                            class="selection">Other</span> <span class="caret"></span>
                    </label>

                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                        <label class="btn btn-primary w-100">
                            <input type="radio" name="options" value="20" id="option3" autocomplete="off"> 20
                        </label>
                        <label class="btn btn-primary w-100">
                            <input type="radio" name="options" value="25" id="option3" autocomplete="off"> 25
                        </label>
                        <label class="btn btn-primary w-100">
                            <input type="radio" name="options" value="30" id="option3" autocomplete="off"> 30
                        </label>
                        <label class="btn btn-primary w-100">
                            <input type="radio" name="options" value="35" id="option3" autocomplete="off"> 35
                        </label>
                        <label class="btn btn-primary w-100">
                            <input type="radio" name="options" value="40" id="option3" autocomplete="off"> 40
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the tutorial on where I was going wrong and showing a working code. Appreciate it :)